# Is logarithm of a negative number meaningless?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, logarithms

Is $\log(-x)$, where $x \in (0, \infty)$ undefined? From solving quadratics I was first told that the discriminant has to be non-negative, since $\sqrt{-a}$, where $a \in (0, \infty)$ is undefined. But this was before learning about Imaginary numbers and the complex plane.

For example, what would $\log_3(-9)$ be? Is there a number $a$ such that $3^a=-9$?

So can you evaluate logarithms of negative numbers?

Comment: You absolutely can, and the extension is due to complex analysis. Assuming the principle branch of $\log z$, consider $z=-1=e^{i \pi}$ and so $\log z = i \pi$. In general, $\log z = \ln|z| + i \pi$

Comment: in complex plane yes.

Comment: It depends whether you allow complex numbers, but even then, the logarithms of negative numbers are not unique, you have to choose a particular branch to make it unique.

Comment: The title asks about a negative logarithm (such as $\log x$ where $x\in(0,1)$) but the body question is about the logarithm of a negative number.

Comment: @bof apologies, the title of the question is written incorrectly.

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has an infinitude of logarithms for each nonzero complex base. For example, if  $z$ is an integer and $i^2=-1$, then the logarithms of $1$ to the base 2 are of the form $i2z/\ln(2)$. When $z=0$, then we havde the uniue real value ($0$).

 I do not know how to extend it to quaternions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to evaluate logarithm of a negative number in the complex plane. Moreover it is possible evaluate [logarithm of any non-zero complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) $z=x+iy\ne0$:
$$
\log z=\ln|z|+i\arg(z).
$$
where the real numbers $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\arg z$ are, respectively, the absolute value and argument of $z$. The argument is essentially the angle in the complex plane between $z$ and positive direction of the real axis. There is however a complication. Different from the real logarithm the complex one is multivalued function, so that any multiple of $2\pi i$ can be added to its value. One of possible solution of the problem is to bound the imaginary part (for example from $-\pi$ to $\pi$).

Equipped with this knowledge and the fact that 
$\log_a z=\frac{\ln z}{\ln a}$:
$$
\log_3(-9)=\frac{\ln9+i\pi}{\ln3}=2+\frac{\pi i}{\ln3}.
$$